# How can I access https webservice with an Android application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, android-webservice

I am not able to work with HTTPS URL in Android webservice.

It's working with HTTP but not with HTTPS.

I don't have any idea how to use HTTPS.

Do I have to add any extra code?

Comment: Please define "not working".  Does it give you an error or exception?  Can you share the url you're trying to connect to?

Comment: If this is your web service, it sounds like maybe the web service isn't configured to use https.  You would need a certificate installed on the web server, and a little bit of configuration to make that happen.  Can you perform a GET request against the web service from your browser like Google Chrome?  If not, then Xamarin has nothing to do with the problem...

Comment: Hello wesam, could you please update with a code snippet of what you are trying to do? also it would help to post any error messages you are receiving

Comment: When I enter web.config and insert this code: <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
 <match url="(.*)" /> 
 <conditions> 
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
 </conditions> 
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer> app stop work on physical android device, whene remove it all things fine.